# How to copy some columns and change one column at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the third and the forth column but change the second column. What should I do? I want to know how to write the sql query. Thank you.

for example:

table1:

```
1, 1, aaa, bbb

2, 1, ads, bff

3, 1, awq, bcc
```

and I want table1 finally to be:

```
1, 1, aaa, bbb

2, 1, ads, bff

3, 1, awq, bcc

4, 2, aaa, bbb

5, 2, ads, bff

6, 2, awq, bcc
```

(the first column is id)

Comment: And the Problem is?

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you have already tried.

Comment: I want to copy the third and the forth column but change the second column. What should I do?

Comment: @Jens I want to know how to write the sql query

Comment: And what is the logic behind it? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: [insert into table1 (column2,column3,column4) values (2, c3, c4) ]

---c3,c4 are [select column3, column4 from table1 where column2 = 1]

I don't know how to put them together @Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
insert into table1 (column2,column3,column4) 
  select 2,column3, column4 
  from table1 where column2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest:

```
select (@cnt:=@cnt + 1) as RowNumber,a.c1,a.c2,a.c3 from
(select 1 as id, 1 as c1, 'aaa' as c2, 'bbb'as c3 union all
select 2, 1, 'ads', 'bff' union all 
select 3, 1, 'awq', 'bcc'

union all

select 1 as id, 1 as c1, 'aaa' as c2, 'bbb'as c3 union all
select 2, 1, 'ads', 'bff' union all 
select 3, 1, 'awq', 'bcc') as a

cross JOIN 

(select @cnt:=0) as tmp
```

RESULT:

```
1   1   aaa bbb
2   1   ads bff
3   1   awq bcc
4   1   aaa bbb
5   1   ads bff
6   1   awq bcc
```